# How to write an OkHttp3 stack for Volley for Android M and above?

Tags: android, android-volley, apache-httpclient-4.x, okhttp

I want to create an `OkHttp3Stack` for Volley which implements `com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack`. The gists currently present [(example)](https://gist.github.com/alashow/c96c09320899e4caa06b) use Apache HTTP which has been removed in Android M. How do I write an `OkHttp3Stack` without Apache Http for Android M and above?

Comment: I have that my question in my mind too https://gist.github.com/intari/e57a945eed9c2ee0f9eb9082469698f3

Comment: Got any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

A per the latest **[Volley 1.1.0 release](https://github.com/google/volley/releases/tag/1.1.0)** we should follow **[Migrating-from-Apache-HTTP](https://github.com/google/volley/wiki/Migrating-from-Apache-HTTP)** while creating OkHttp3 Stack for volley!

here I want to share the code for OkHttp3 Stack for Volley 1.1.0 release which doesn't uses any of the **[deprecated apache dependencies](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)** !!

Source code: [VolleyOkHttp3StackInterceptors.java](https://gist.github.com/LOG-TAG/3ad1c191b3ca7eab3ea6834386e30eb9) (Tested)